# How to run a program using Valgrind in Clion?

Tags: intellij-idea, valgrind, clion

How can I run my program using valgrind directly in CLion using the run configuration ? I found how to add parameters when I launch my program, but how can I launch valgrind like :

> valgrind my_program arg1 --arg2 ...

And how can I change easily the parameters without going on the "Edit configuration" panel to add, for example, valgrind options ?

Comment: I think that for now you may use your console. But please have a look at it (and maybe add a vote) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valgrind is now natively supported in [CLion 2017.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/11/clion-2017-3-cpp-support-valgrind-memcheck-boost-test/).

Answer (score 4):

You could create a [custom target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html) in your `CMakeLists.txt` that runs your program under valgrind.